# Resident Set Size (RSS) limit has no effect

Tags: python, resources, limits, pam, ulimit

The following problem occurs on a machine running Ubuntu 10.04 with the 2.6.32-22-generic kernel: Setting a limit for the Resident Set Size (RSS) of a process does not seem to have any effect. I currently set the limit in Python with the following code:

```
import resource
# (100, 100) is the (soft, hard) limit. ~100kb.
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_RSS, (100, 100))
memory_sink = ['a']*10000000   # this should fail
```

The list, memory_sink, succeeds every time. When I check RSS usage with top, I can easily get the process to use 1gb of RAM, which means that the limit is not working. Do RSS limits not work with this kernel or distro? If it helps, resource.RLIMIT_NPROC (user process limit) does work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Form the `getrlimit` manpage:

> ```
> RLIMIT_RSS
> Specifies the limit (in pages) of  the  process's  resident  set
> (the  number of virtual pages resident in RAM).  This limit only
> has effect in Linux 2.4.x, x < 30, and there only affects  calls
> to madvise(2) specifying MADV_WILLNEED.
> ```

It seems this is just not supported on Linux kernel 2.6.

Comment: I had googled the man page countless times, but missed the ones that had this provision. A simple "man getrlimit" on my machine would have sufficed. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

You can accomplish this using cgroups.  The long version is on my [blog](http://jlebar.com/2011/6/15/Limiting_the_amount_of_RAM_a_program_can_use.html), but the short version (tested on Ubuntu 11.04) is:

- Install the `cgroup-bin` package.
- Edit `/etc/cgconfig.config` and create a group with limited memory.  For
  instance, I added:

  ```
  group limited {
    memory {
      memory.limit_in_bytes = 50M;
    }
  }
  ```
- Run

  ```
  $ sudo restart cgconfig
  $ sudo chown -R jlebar /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/limited
  $ cgexec -g memory:limited your/program
  ```

I observed my process with an RSS of 93M when I asked it to use only 50M, but that wasn't a problem for me, since my goal was just to get the program to page.

`cgclassify` lets you attach restrictions to a running process too. Note for RSS this only applies to memory allocated after the restriction comes into effect.

Comment: On Ubuntu 11.10 the config file location changed to: `/etc/cgconfig.conf`

Comment: On Ubuntu 10.04 I just get the error message `restart: Unknown job: cgconfig` when trying to run the `sudo restart cgconfig` command. :(

Comment: I do not have root.  Can I still use this?

Comment: For newer Ubuntus (I tried on 16.04): https://askubuntu.com/a/848022/65575 (`cgconfigparser -l /etc/cgconfig.config`)

Answer (score 4):

A related limit - virtual memory or address space (RLIMIT_AS) - does work. This allows limiting the python process and subprocesses memory without external tools.

```
>>> size = 50*1024*1024 # In bytes
>>> resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS, (size, resource.RLIM_INFINITY))
>>> a = 'a' * size
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
```

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit):

> **RLIMIT_AS**. The maximum size of the process's virtual memory (address space) in bytes.

Here is a good explanation of the difference between the Resident Set and the VM size - [What is RSS and VSZ in Linux memory management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880784/what-is-rss-and-vsz-in-linux-memory-management).

Comment: When I try to use `RLIMIT_AS`, I get a `MemoryError` even when allocating (much) less than the limit.  [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39755928/974555).

Comment: @gerrit This might come from the fact that `RLIMIT_AS` "includes all memory that the process can access, including memory that is swapped out, memory that is allocated, but not used, and memory that is from shared libraries." https://stackoverflow.com/a/21049737/1116842

Answer (score 1):

I created a script to limit memory usage using cgroups and cgroup manager, useable for ad-hoc commands and not needing root privileges. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134414/how-to-limit-the-total-resources-memory-of-a-process-and-its-children/174894#174894