# Why ulimit can't limit resident memory successfully and how?

Tags: linux, shell, administration, ulimit

I start a new bash shell, and execute:

```
ulimit -m 102400
ulimit -a
"
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 20
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 16382
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) 102400
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
"
```

and then ,I execute compiling a huge project. the Linking of it will use large memory, more then 2G. The result, process ld used more then 2G resident memory.

is there any wrong ? how to use ulimit or can I use other programs to limit resident memory?

the target of limit resident memory, is because computer will freeze when one process almost used all memory.

Comment: should move to serverfault.com ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the man page for [`setrlimit`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html):

> **RLIMIT_RSS**
>
> Specifies the limit (in pages) of the process's resident set (the number of virtual pages resident in RAM).  This limit only has effect in Linux 2.4.x, x < 30, and there only affects calls to madvise(2) specifying MADV_WILLNEED

You probably want to set the virtual memory size instead, via `ulimit -v`

Comment: NO, I just want to limit the resident memory. If I limit the virtual memory, the ld program will terminate executing, and report the memory is exhausted.

Comment: For the particular problem you had (large amounts of memory used for linking) it might help to use the gold linker instead of ld.

Answer (score 5):

You can restrict the resident memory using cgroups.  See [Resident Set Size (RSS) limit has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043709/resident-set-size-rss-limit-has-no-effect/6365534#6365534)