# Python resource module not work

Tags: python, linux

(forgive my poor English, I am not native)

I tried Python resource module to limit child process.

It seems that setting RLIMIT_CPU can successfully limit the amount of cputime, but others like RLIMIT_RSS didn't work at all.

For example, I use following script to call child.py, and set RSS limit to (1024, 1024):

```
import os
import sys
import resource
import subprocess

def setlimits():
    resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_RSS, (1024, 1024))

p = subprocess.Popen(["./child.py"], preexec_fn=setlimits)
print(p.wait())
```

child.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import resource

print("RSS limit: ", resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_RSS))
a=[]
while True:
    a.append(1) # deadloop, until eat up memory
```

Child process print "RSS limit:  (1024, 1024)" and then continue to run until killed.
I can see child.py eating my memory but RLIMIT_RSS didn't work.

My OS is latest Archlinux (2.6.39 kernel), and Python is ver3.2.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043709/resident-set-size-rss-limit-has-no-effect. The link also provides solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation for [setrlimit()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit), `RLIMIT_RSS` has no effect in Linux 2.4.30 and later. Also, it only counts memory marked with [madvise()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/madvise):

> **RLIMIT_RSS**
>   Specifies the limit (in pages) of the process's resident set (the number
>   of virtual pages resident in RAM).
>   This limit only has effect in Linux
>   2.4.x, x < 30, and there only affects calls to `madvise()` specifying
>   `MADV_WILLNEED`.

So, if you really want to limit processes this way, you'll have to run a 2.4 kernel and hack the Python interpreter so it calls `madvise()` on allocated memory, which will probably have unexpected side-effects.

Comment: Is there any other ways to limit memory usage?

Comment: @cuihao, did you try `RLIMIT_AS`?