# Why does docker see the container is hitting the rss limit?

Tags: memory, docker, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to understand why the limits have decided a task needs to be killed, and how it's doing the accounting. When my GCE Docker container kills a process, it shows something like:

```
Task in /404daacfcf6b9e55f71b3d7cac358f0dc921a2d580eed460c2826aea8e43f05e killed as a result of limit of /404daacfcf6b9e55f71b3d7cac358f0dc921a2d580eed460c2826aea8e43f05e 
memory: usage 2097152kB, limit 2097152kB, failcnt 74571 
memory+swap: usage 0kB, limit 18014398509481983kB, failcnt 0 
kmem: usage 0kB, limit 18014398509481983kB, failcnt 0 
Memory cgroup stats for /404daacfcf6b9e55f71b3d7cac358f0dc921a2d580eed460c2826aea8e43f05e: cache:368KB rss:2096784KB rss_huge:0KB mapped_file:0KB writeback:0KB inactive_anon:16KB active_anon:2097040KB inactive_file:60KB active_file:36KB unevictable:0KB 
[ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes swapents oom_score_adj name 
[ 4343]     0  4343     5440       65      15        0             0 bash 
[ 4421]     0  4421   265895     6702      77        0             0 npm 
[ 4422]     0  4422    12446     2988      28        0             0 gunicorn 
[ 4557]     0  4557   739241   346035    1048        0             0 gunicorn 
[ 4560]     0  4560     1086       24       8        0             0 sh 
[ 4561]     0  4561     5466      103      15        0             0 bash 
[14594]     0 14594   387558   168790     672        0             0 node 
Memory cgroup out of memory: Kill process 4557 (gunicorn) score 662 or sacrifice child 
Killed process 4557 (gunicorn) total-vm:2956964kB, anon-rss:1384140kB, file-rss:0kB
```

Supposedly the memory hit a 2GB usage limit, and something needs to die. According to the cgroup stats, I appear to have 2GB of usage in `active_anon` and `rss`.

When I look at the table of process stats, I don't see where the 2GB is:

For `rss`, I see the two major processes `346035 + 168790 = 514MB`?
For `total_vm`, I see three major processes `265895 + 739241 + 387558 = 1.4GB`?

But when it decides to kill the gunicorn process, it says it had 3GB of Total VM and 1.4GB of Anon RSS. I don't see how this follows from the above numbers at all...

For most of it's life, according to `top`, the gunicorn process appears to hum along with `555m RES` and `2131m VIRT` and `22% MEM * 2.5GB box = 550MB` of memory usage. (I haven't yet been able to time it properly to peek at `top` values at the time it dies...)

- Can someone help me understand this?
- Under what accounting, do these sum to 2GB of usage? (virtual? rss? something else?)
- Is there something else besides `top`/`ps` I should use to track how much memory a process is using for the purposes of docker's killing it?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, the total_vm and rss are counted in 4kB (refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43611576), instead of kB.

So for pid<4557>:

- rss=346035, means anon-rss:1384140kB (=346035*4kB)
- total_vm=739241, means total-vm:2956964kB(=739241*4kB)

This will explain your mem usage very well.