# Results from ps -e, rss versus vsz

Tags: linux, ubuntu, embedded, gnome-terminal

I am currently working on a memory leak issue that we have in our software. I have created a bash script which logs the rss and vsz information from ps. What I see from the results is that the vsz goes parallel with the rss results. Is this somewhat expected? What I was planning to see how much my process consumes from the physical memory and how much it is consuming from the shared memory. Can you comment on this?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the process memory isn't swapped out, it is expected that "the vsz goes parallel with the rss". Did you read e. g. [What is RSS and VSZ in Linux memory management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880784/what-is-rss-and-vsz-in-linux-memory-management)?