# Error upstream timed out. What is wrong with my setup?

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I am running wordpress 3.9.1 on a 2GB ram / 2x CPU digitalocean vps with nginx and php5-fpm on tcp/ip 127.0.0.1:9000 under debian 7 x64. I am experiencing massive 504 gateway timeouts. 
    nginx log output is:
    upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream or 
    upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream

```
www.conf:
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 25
pm.start_servers = 4
pm.min_spare_servers = 4
pm.max_spare_servers = 8
pm.max_requests = 200
listen_backlog = 65536
request_terminate_timeout = 30

php.ini:
max_execution_time = 30

nginx.conf:
worker_processes 2;
worker_connections 1024;
client_max_body_size 10M;
fastcgi_read_timeout 30s;
client_header_timeout 30s;
client_body_timeout 30s;
fastcgi_send_timeout 30s;    
fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
keepalive_timeout 65;
gzip on;

The recommended settings of DO for the sysctl.conf are:    
# Digital Ocean Recommended Settings:
net.core.wmem_max=12582912
net.core.rmem_max=12582912
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem= 10240 87380 12582912
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem= 10240 87380 12582912

the following was removed completely:
php5-fpm.conf (/etc/nginx/conf.d/):
upstream php5-fpm-sock { 
server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; 
}
```

I also tried to disable my plugins with no luck. The site becomes unresponsive while the wordpress dashboard shows "connection lost" message and eventually 504 gateway timeout.

Anyone with a similar experience?
Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Nginx worker_processes should correlate directly to the CPU threads; since you have a 2 core CPU then you should have 2 worker_processes threads.

Next, try increasing the php-fpm servers to x4 of CPU threads. Something like:

```
pm.start_servers = 4
pm.min_spare_servers = 4
pm.max_spare_servers = 8
```

Also, nginx is complaining of the upstream timeouts. Do you have any upstream confs/servers ?

Comment: Before changing to 127.0.0.1:9000 (from unix socket) i was using an upstream php5-fpm.conf in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ that had: 
    upstream php5-fpm-sock {
    server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }

Comment: Can you post that config up ?

Comment: I've added the upstream conf file configuration in my question block. Can you please check?

Comment: You don't need that if you are using TCP. Just remove it.

Comment: I just removed it. Thanks, I will send updates later today with progress. I want to also mention that i am not using varnish nor memcache.

Comment: Unfortunately no luck. I am still experiencing random 504 timeout errors. I've updated my question block with the latest tweaks. Any other suggestions @Rijndael?

Comment: Is the error msg the same as the original post? You will need to restart nginx if your remove that conf. If its still complaining of upstream errors then you have an upstream config somewhere that is causing the issue.

Comment: Yes the message is the same. It less frequent but still exists. The initial guide i followed to setup the server was this: [link](http://www.cryptkcoding.com/2011/08/running-wordpress-with-nginx-php-fpm-apc-and-varnish/) up to the point where the apc is installed. Can you please have a look to the guide in case that there is something that is still causing the 504? @Rijndael

Comment: That guide is somewhat outdated on the PHP front. If you've installed php 5.5 then use opcache instead of apc. How are you testing for '504' errors ? If you are using a benchmarking tool then yes you will get 504s because you are pushing the setup to the limit; benchmarks are synthetic and not representative of real world scenarios but merely give you a hint of how far you can push your system.

Comment: I have 5.4 (dotdeb repo) installed. 504 happens usually when the wordpress admin is doing work in the dashboard and there is high traffic on the site. I don't run or use any benchmark tools at the moment. @Rijndael

Comment: Okay. Try to increase the min_spare_servers and min_start_servers to 8 and max_spare_servers to 16 and max_requests to 500. Remember to restart phpfpm. If you still get timeouts then you will probably need to upgrade your server to 4GB. An alternative is to use a cache server such as varnish but then you'll have issues with cache expiration and keeping pages up to date.