# Error on Kafka producer when application logs transferring to Kafka consumer

Tags: php, logging, apache-kafka

I have configured 3 Instances for a basic start to configure Kafka as sending Application logs to another machine.

There are PHP logs are transferring.

I have installed PHP, Nginx, PHPrdKafka, kafka_2.11-1.0.1., librdkafka, libsasl2-dev, libssl-dev, zlib1g-dev, libpthread-stubs0-dev, build-essential.

1 instance is working as producer, 2nd working as a broker and the last working as a consumer. When I start to test logs were continuously going to the consumer but the load on producer was getting high and an error occurs on producer:

> 2018/03/23 07:07:50 [error] 9819#9819: *539 connect() to
>   unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily
>   unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 35.190.64.128,
>   server: api-useast.midarexdigital.com, request: "POST
>   /rtb/70b4bf164fd840f80afe320b1ad98234 HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host:
>   "exchange.adnexus.mobi".

help me out with this.I am not getting any Clue.

Comment: What is rpm in producer side ? and what is configuration of socket.timeout.ms?

Comment: Each producer instance has 1000 RPS and configuration of  socket.timeout.ms =60000

Comment: Seems to be there is nothing problem with kafka, can u check below links once : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098029/connect-to-unix-var-run-php5-fpm-sock-failed-what-is-wrong-with-my-setup,    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470109/error-502-in-nginx-php5-fpm