# How to solve PHP-FPM error [pool www] seems busy?

Tags: php, configuration, webserver

There is a PHP-FPM warning in my `php7.2-fpm.log`:

```
WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 0 idle, and 339 total children
```

I have to restart server every time I get this overtwise it does not respond to any request.

My server:

```
CPU Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1245 V2 @ 3.40GHz
Number : 8
Cache : 8192 KB
Speed :  3600 MHz
RAM  4 x 8192 MB
```

Configuration `www.conf` which has been edited a lot of times:

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 900
pm.start_servers = 95
pm.min_spare_servers = 50
pm.max_spare_servers = 150
pm.max_requests = 600
```

I have about 100 PHP workers processing tasks in background and a couple of Swoole Servers handling requests to my API.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Explanation here has suggestions on how to edit the www.conf in a logical way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25097179/warning-pool-www-seems-busy-you-may-need-to-increase-pm-start-servers-or-pm