# How does spark.python.worker.memory relate to spark.executor.memory?

Tags: memory, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

[This diagram](http://0x0fff.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Spark-Architecture-On-YARN.png) is quite clear on the relationship between the different YARN and Spark memory related settings, except when it comes to `spark.python.worker.memory`.

How does `spark.python.worker.memory` fit into this memory model?

Are the Python processes governed by `spark.executor.memory` or `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb`?

**Update**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31565497/what-is-spark-python-worker-memory) explains what the setting does, but doesn't answer the question concerning the memory governance, or how it relates to other memory settings.

Comment: Appears to be discussed here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31565497/what-is-spark-python-worker-memory

Comment: That answer explains what the setting does, not how it relates to the rest of the spark memory model.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Found this thread](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/spark-is-running-extremely-slow-with-larger-data-set-like-2G-td17152.html) from the Apache-spark mailing list, and it appears that spark.python.worker.memory is a subset of the memory from spark.executor.memory.

From the thread: "spark.python.worker.memory is used for Python worker in executor"