# What is the difference between “spark.python.worker.memory” and "spark.executor.pyspark.memory"?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

What is the difference between “spark.python.worker.memory” and "spark.executor.pyspark.memory" ?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. I believe your question is [answered in an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36594056/how-does-spark-python-worker-memory-relate-to-spark-executor-memory). It is usually good practice to check if there are already existing answers. Enjoy.