# Difference between Resident Set Size (RSS) and Java total committed memory (NMT) for a JVM running in Docker container

Tags: java, linux, memory, docker, jvm

**Scenario:**

I have a JVM running in a docker container. I did some memory analysis using two tools: 1) **top** 2) **Java Native Memory Tracking**. The numbers look confusing and I am trying to find whats causing the differences.

**Question:**

The RSS is reported as 1272MB for the Java process and the Total Java Memory is reported as 790.55 MB. How can I explain where did the rest of the memory 1272 - 790.55 = 481.44 MB go?

**Why I want to keep this issue open even after looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173374) on SO:**

I did see the answer and the explanation makes sense. However, after getting output from Java NMT and pmap -x , **I am still not able to concretely map which java memory addresses are actually resident and physically mapped**. I need some concrete explanation (with detailed steps) to find whats causing this difference between RSS and Java Total committed memory.

**Top Output**

[image]

**Java NMT**

[image]

**Docker memory stats**

[image]

**Graphs**

I have a docker container running for most than 48 hours. Now, when I see a graph which contains:

1. Total memory given to the docker container  = 2 GB
2. Java Max Heap = 1 GB
3. Total committed (JVM) = always less than 800 MB
4. Heap Used (JVM) = always less than 200 MB
5. Non Heap Used (JVM) = always less than 100 MB.
6. RSS = around 1.1 GB.

So, whats eating the memory between 1.1 GB (RSS) and 800 MB (Java Total committed memory)?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a JVM report more committed memory than the linux process resident set size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173374/why-does-a-jvm-report-more-committed-memory-than-the-linux-process-resident-set) ... well, an inverse thereof.

Comment: I have the same problem and kind find the answers :( What kind of application do you have?

Comment: Did you find the answer to your previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/a/38630406/6309) satisfactory?

Comment: @sunsin1985 you might try to change malloc implementation to jemalloc, i've seen RSS decrease significantly after that. See https://gdstechnology.blog.gov.uk/2015/12/11/using-jemalloc-to-get-to-the-bottom-of-a-memory-leak/

I have an application running with 600MB heap and 1.3GB RSS - I didn't investigate that closely yet, but the memory is simply missing - there is no significant native memory allocated. I suspect that this is due to memory fragmentation (and that's why jemalloc helps)

Comment: If you are tracking Java native memory leaks or would like to minimize RSS usage, there is this question with answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041117/growing-resident-memory-usage-rss-of-java-process/35610063

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You have some clue in "
[Analyzing java memory usage in a Docker container](http://trustmeiamadeveloper.com/2016/03/18/where-is-my-memory-java/)" from [Mikhail Krestjaninoff](https://github.com/krestjaninoff):

(And to be clear, in May 2019, three years later, [the **situation does improves** with openJDK 8u212](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56153528/6309) )

> **R**esident **S**et **S**ize is the amount of physical memory currently allocated and used by a process (without swapped out pages). It includes the code, data and shared libraries (which are counted in every process which uses them)
>
> Why does docker stats info differ from the ps data?
>
> Answer for the first question is very simple - [Docker has a bug (or a feature - depends on your mood)](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/10824): it includes file caches into the total memory usage info. So, we can just avoid this metric and use `ps` info about RSS.
>
> Well, ok - but **why is RSS higher than Xmx?**
>
> Theoretically, in case of a java application

```
RSS = Heap size + MetaSpace + OffHeap size
```

> where OffHeap consists of thread stacks, direct buffers, mapped files (libraries and jars) and JVM code itse
>
> Since [JDK 1.8.40](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/enhancements-8.html) we have **[Native Memory Tracker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr007.html)**!
>
> As you can see, I’ve already added `-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary` property to the JVM, so we can just invoke it from the command line:

```
docker exec my-app jcmd 1 VM.native_memory summary
```

(This is what the OP did)

> Don’t worry about the “Unknown” section - seems that NMT is an immature tool and can’t deal with CMS GC (this section disappears when you use an another GC).
>
> Keep in mind, **that NMT displays “committed” memory, not "resident" (which you get through the ps command). In other words, a memory page can be committed without considering as a resident (until it directly accessed)**.
>
> **That means that NMT results for non-heap areas (heap is always preinitialized) might be bigger than RSS values**.

(that is where "[Why does a JVM report more committed memory than the linux process resident set size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31173374/6309)" comes in)

> As a result, despite the fact that we set the jvm heap limit to 256m, our application consumes 367M. The “other” 164M are mostly used for storing class metadata, compiled code, threads and GC data.
>
> First three points are often constants for an application, so the only thing which increases with the heap size is GC data.
>   This dependency is linear, but the “`k`” coefficient (`y = kx + b`) is much less then 1.

---

More generally, this seems to be followed by [issue 15020](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15020) which reports a similar issue since docker 1.7

> I'm running a simple Scala (JVM) application which loads a lot of data into and out of memory.
>   I set the JVM to 8G heap (`-Xmx8G`). I have a machine with 132G memory, and it can't handle more than 7-8 containers because they grow well past the 8G limit I imposed on the JVM.

([`docker stat`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stats/) was [reported as misleading before](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/10824#issuecomment-130681068), as it apparently includes file caches into the total memory usage info)

> [`docker stat`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stats/) shows that each container itself is using much more memory than the JVM is supposed to be using. For instance:

```
CONTAINER CPU % MEM USAGE/LIMIT MEM % NET I/O
dave-1 3.55% 10.61 GB/135.3 GB 7.85% 7.132 MB/959.9 MB
perf-1 3.63% 16.51 GB/135.3 GB 12.21% 30.71 MB/5.115 GB
```

> **It almost seems that the JVM is asking the OS for memory, which is allocated within the container, and the JVM is freeing memory as its GC runs, but the container doesn't release the memory back to the main OS.   So... memory leak.**

Comment: thanks for your reply! I just attached a graph to the original question. The thing is that, as per the summary that you have provided, if JVM was asking the OS for memory, then when  the heap used grows up, then RSS should have also shot up. And, when GC would have happened, the heap used would have come down but the RSS wouldn't have. But, when I see the graphs, I do see that right from the word go, there is a considerable gap between RSS and Java total committed memory. How can I explain this gap?

Comment: @sunsin1985 "whats eating the memory between 1.1 GB (RSS) and 800 MB (Java Total committed memory)?" I suspect those are the "storing class metadata, compiled code, threads and GC data" referenced in the article, plus GC might not free anything if the container keep not releasing it.

Comment: thanks, but won't that be part of the "total committed" number obtained from Java NMT?

Comment: @sunsin1985 True (unless your graph is stacking values one on top of the others)

Comment: @sunsin1985 another good read: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-memory-issues, where the full java option becomes `JAVA_OPTS="-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=detail -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintNMTStatistics"`

Comment: @sunsin1985 another interpretation of RSS (in a docker context): http://stackoverflow.com/a/36511485/6309

Comment: @VonC remember that NMTdoesn't track memory allocations by non-JVM code, so allocations via JNI or event direct ByteBuffers are not there.

Comment: I think the answer here is not to the question asked. The question was why java process RSS > JVM heap+non_heap. The answer is to the opposite question:  
why JVM heap+non_heap might be > java process RSS. @VonC am I missing something?

Comment: @ArtemNakonechny (three years later): yes, that is what I found at the time. But again, with recent JDK8 releases, that has changed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56153528/6309

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I am not an expert

I had a production incident recently when under heavy load, pods had a big jump in RSS and Kubernetes killed the pods. There was no OOM error exception, but Linux stopped the process in the most hardcore way.

There was a big gap between RSS and total reserved space by JVM. Heap memory, native memory, threads, everything looked ok, however RSS was big.

It was found out that it is due to the fact how malloc works internally. There are big gaps in the memory where malloc takes chunks of memory from. If there are a lot of cores on your machine, malloc tries to adapt and give every core each own space to take free memory from to avoid resource contention. Setting up `export MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=2` solved the issue. You can find more about this situation here:

1. [Growing resident memory usage (RSS) of Java Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041117/growing-resident-memory-usage-rss-of-java-process/28935139#28935139)
2. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/tuning-glibc-memory-behavior
3. https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Malloc-Tunable-Parameters.html
4. https://github.com/jeffgriffith/native-jvm-leaks

P.S. I don't know why there was a jump in RSS memory. Pods are built on Spring Boot + Kafka.