# Unexplained extra memory consumed by docker running java process

Tags: java, docker, memory

### What we have :

- Java app running in docker container
- No native code called, no processed launched, no DLLs / .so files referenced.
- JVM args : `-Xmx256m -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary`
- Docker hard memory limit set to `768m`
- JVM seems normal (normal GC cycles, no memory leaks, no OOMs)
- Docker memory keeps growing until it reaches hard limit (`768m`) resulting in killing and restarting the container.

### The Issue :

- Why does the docker stats memory keep on growing (resulting in the hard memory limit being hit every day) despite the fact that the JVM seems to be behaving within its limits.

[image]

- With other microservices we don't see this behavior

[image]

### JVM

On the JVM side we don't notice anything special :

[image]

### Docker stats output :

```
492.8MiB / 768MiB     64.17%              

[ec2-user@ip-10-180-28-222 ~]$ docker exec 34d7 jcmd 1 VM.native_memory summary
1:

Native Memory Tracking:

Total: reserved=1731355KB, committed=472227KB
-                 Java Heap (reserved=262144KB, committed=262144KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=262144KB, committed=262144KB)

-                     Class (reserved=1131805KB, committed=92829KB)
                            (classes #16224)
                            (malloc=7453KB #20996)
                            (mmap: reserved=1124352KB, committed=85376KB)

-                    Thread (reserved=29932KB, committed=29932KB)
                            (thread #30)
                            (stack: reserved=29772KB, committed=29772KB)
                            (malloc=94KB #151)
                            (arena=66KB #55)

-                      Code (reserved=255659KB, committed=35507KB)
                            (malloc=6059KB #9814)
                            (mmap: reserved=249600KB, committed=29448KB)

-                        GC (reserved=15369KB, committed=15369KB)
                            (malloc=5785KB #547)
                            (mmap: reserved=9584KB, committed=9584KB)

-                  Compiler (reserved=190KB, committed=190KB)
                            (malloc=59KB #858)
                            (arena=131KB #6)

-                  Internal (reserved=7849KB, committed=7849KB)
                            (malloc=7817KB #18468)
                            (mmap: reserved=32KB, committed=32KB)

-                    Symbol (reserved=20018KB, committed=20018KB)
                            (malloc=17325KB #175818)
                            (arena=2693KB #1)

-    Native Memory Tracking (reserved=3558KB, committed=3558KB)
                            (malloc=10KB #120)
                            (tracking overhead=3548KB)

-               Arena Chunk (reserved=4830KB, committed=4830KB)
                            (malloc=4830KB)
```

After running for about 20 hours

```
649.6MiB / 768MiB     84.59%               

[ec2-user@ip-10-180-28-222 ~]$ docker exec 34d7 jcmd 1 VM.native_memory summary
1:

Native Memory Tracking:

Total: reserved=1741020KB, committed=510928KB
-                 Java Heap (reserved=262144KB, committed=262144KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=262144KB, committed=262144KB)

-                     Class (reserved=1138319KB, committed=100495KB)
                            (classes #16390)
                            (malloc=7823KB #30851)
                            (mmap: reserved=1130496KB, committed=92672KB)

-                    Thread (reserved=30996KB, committed=30996KB)
                            (thread #31)
                            (stack: reserved=30800KB, committed=30800KB)
                            (malloc=97KB #156)
                            (arena=99KB #57)

-                      Code (reserved=261330KB, committed=69062KB)
                            (malloc=11730KB #16047)
                            (mmap: reserved=249600KB, committed=57332KB)

-                        GC (reserved=15363KB, committed=15363KB)
                            (malloc=5779KB #334)
                            (mmap: reserved=9584KB, committed=9584KB)

-                  Compiler (reserved=223KB, committed=223KB)
                            (malloc=92KB #1246)
                            (arena=131KB #6)

-                  Internal (reserved=8358KB, committed=8358KB)
                            (malloc=8326KB #18561)
                            (mmap: reserved=32KB, committed=32KB)

-                    Symbol (reserved=20253KB, committed=20253KB)
                            (malloc=17527KB #177997)
                            (arena=2725KB #1)

-    Native Memory Tracking (reserved=3846KB, committed=3846KB)
                            (malloc=10KB #127)
                            (tracking overhead=3836KB)

-               Arena Chunk (reserved=188KB, committed=188KB)
                            (malloc=188KB)
```

### Observations

What we know so far after observation for 20 hours  :

- Docker stats jumped from `492.8MiB` to `649.6MiB`
- JVM committed native memory jumped from `472227KB` to `510928KB`
- The gap between the docker stats and JVM committed native memory seems to be growing. (where is the `649.6MiB - 510928KB` and why is it growing)
- JVM stats remain normal throughout this period.

So I don't know what else I can debug on the JVM side. I understand java needs more than just the heap (hence the native memory tracking), but there is still a gap of around 150m between what the jvm native memory tracker reports and what the docker stats is seeing. How can I gain some more insights in where that memory is going ?

Comment: How does your dockerfile look like?

Comment: https://github.com/IxorTalk/ixortalk-authserver/blob/master/src/main/docker/Dockerfile   The `JAVA_OPTS` we pass are set by cloudformation templates but the only thing we pass is `-Xmx256m` (and recently the `-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary` for debugging

Comment: you might want to cross-post this question to DevOpsSE

Comment: I think this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38670876/482811 should help you understand the discrepancies and maybe solve your problem. And note that the first metrics you are checking are the internal Java heap, which is a (usually big) fraction of the total memory a Java application is using. So indeed the Java heap size might always be below your limit, it does not tell you much about the other Java memory usage though: GC, stacks, memory mapped outside the heap, etc.

Comment: Next to native memory, you also might want to run jcmd with the following flags: VM.stringtable / VM.symboltable.

Answer (score 4):

JVM reported memory is not everything.

> ### JVM’s memory footprint
>
> So, what contributes to the JVM memory footprint? Most of us who have
>   run a Java application, know how to set the maximum heap space. But
>   there’s actually a lot more contributing to the memory footprint:
>
> - Native JRE
> - Perm / metaspace
> - JIT bytecode
> - JNI
> - NIO
> - Threads
>
> This is a lot that needs to be kept in mind when we want to set memory
>   limits with Docker containers. And also setting the container memory
>   limit to the maximum heap space, might not be sufficient…
>
> #### JVM and CPUs
>
> Let’s take a short look at how the JVM adjusts to the number of
>   processors/cores available on the node it is running on. There are
>   actually a number of parameters which, by default are initialised based
>   on core count.
>
> - ♯ of JIT compiler threads
> - ♯ Garbage Collection threads
> - ♯ of thread in the common fork-join pool
>     …
>
> So if the JVM is running on a 32 core node (and one did not overwrite
>   the default), the JVM will spawn 32 Garbage Collection threads, 32 JIT
>   compiler threads, …. [source](https://jaxenter.com/nobody-puts-java-container-139373.html)

To prevent this problem, you should use [`+UseContainerSupport`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54516988/1387612) (available since 8u191 enabled by default in Java 10) and probably `-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=90.0` or less depending on your observed total used memory. For more see [this](https://medium.com/adorsys/usecontainersupport-to-the-rescue-e77d6cfea712) and [that](https://medium.com/adorsys/jvm-memory-settings-in-a-container-environment-64b0840e1d9e).

I strongly recommend: ["Nobody puts Java in the container: Ken Sipe"](https://vimeo.com/181900266) from JavaZone

Comment: The OP is asking about the difference between NMT and memory usage. Your post seems to be mixing up NMT and heap usage. NMT does track Threads, perm/metaspace, JIT bytecode, JRE, and direct byte buffers. If you look at the entries in his NMT output, you can see most of these things listed directly. But it can't track JNI allocations and there are other allocations it's missing as well. Further OP already has his max heap set to 256m, with a memory limit of 768Mb.  UseContainerSupport would allocate more max heap than he's given here.

Comment: Continued, UseContainerSupport for memory limits under 1 GB allocate 50% of the memory limit, this would be 384mb significantly more than 256mb and would in-fact make his problem worse. I think probably the only recourse in this case is to further increase the memory limit of the cgroup.

Answer (score 1):

A. Please read janisz answer carefully and follow the links, its a lot of very important information for people who are using Java in containers or otherwise under cgroups.

B. The main issue is that the JVM doesn't see the memory limit on the container: it believes it has the entire free memory of the host OS to play with. When it tries to consume more memory than the cgroup limit allows, the kernel/docker kills the container for violating the cgroup memory limit promise. This is what `-XX:+UseContainerSupport` and the older `-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap` flags are supposed to fix: let the JVM know what the true limits are.

## Additional Info

The `-Xmx` flag does not limit all the memory the JVM - as a Linux process - requires from the operating system. All the machniations of the JVM itself, including the Java stack, metaspace, loaded code, etc (as discussed in janisz' answer) does take memory space as well.

Unfortunately, the JVM likes to take as much memory from the operating system as it needs and prefers to take more memory (if it thinks it is available) then reusing existing (and possibly releasable) memory. Improvements to this behavior (i.e. not assuming the JVM is the only actor in the system) are planned as part of the new [G1 garbage collector](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/346) that ships with Java 12, but unless you have that working for you, the JVM will always grow in its memory usage and will prefer to consume all available free memory, assuming that the sole purpose of the operating system is to provide services for this one JVM it is running.