# JDK12 memory behavior in docker container

Tags: java, docker, openjdk-12

It was my understanding that as of JDK12 the old experimental flag `-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap` was removed but going to be baseline e.g. all JDK12 apps would read cgroup memory and set that as `-Xms` and `-Xmx` internally by default. However when I ran `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` with no `-Xmx` specified it showed I had only 512MB of memory for MaxHeap in a container with a limit of 2GB of memory allocated.

Did I miss something and the community decided to remove the `-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap` flag with no intention of supporting  behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct. Java 12 respects cgroup RAM limit (2GB) and ignores the total RAM available on the host (which is larger than 2GB). Since `-Xmx` wasn't specified the default JVM behavior is to use 25% of available RAM and you end up with 512 MB heap. In practice `-Xmx` is a specific value which overrides `-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap` and other flags governing dynamic heap sizing.

Assuming you don't want to specify `-Xmx` directly you most likely want to use `-XX:MaxRAMFraction=1` which will make the JVM use 100% of the available RAM. Do note that [under load it may kill the container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50261206/1602555).

Comment: thank you that last part is what I didn't understand about it setting it to 25%. I'll add the MaxRAMFraction to something more reasonable.

Comment: Also check [`-XX:+UseContainerSupport`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54517077/1602555).