# How to configure JVM hotspot configurations for Spring Boot application when running inside docker?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, jvm, jvm-hotspot

I'm using the Dockerfile to pass the JVM configuration as follows.

```
FROM openjdk:11
COPY build/libs/api.jar /app/
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Xms256m", "-Xmx256m", "-jar", "app/api.jar"]
```

After building and running the container I goto the bash inside the container and execute
`java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep MaxHeapSize`
command to check if it is configured correctly. But the passed configurations(256mb max heap size) is not added correctly. What am I doing wrong here? I tried setting with environment variables as well. Still same result

Comment: Try CMD instead of ENTRYPOINT

Comment: Still no change. It shows 4gb which is 1/4 of my total memory

Comment: `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` runs *new* Java process, unrelated to the command specified in `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD`

Comment: Use `jcmd <pid> VM.flags` or `jcmd <pid> GC.heap_info` instead

Comment: Instead of using Xms and Xms parameters, it it probably a better choice to let the JVM size the heap based on the available memory in the container: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54516988/what-does-usecontainersupport-vm-parameter-do