# What are the performance impacts of enabling Java Native Memory Tracking (NMT)?

Tags: java

I am trying to diagnose memory issues for a java process running in Docker under Kubernetes.

Java version is Java 8 (1.8.0):

```
root@myHost:/# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_181"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-2~deb9u1-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

I see much of the online discussion and suggestions [and questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38597965/difference-between-resident-set-size-rss-and-java-total-committed-memory-nmt) involve the use of [Native Memory Tracking](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/nmt-8.html).

If I enable NMT, what negative impacts can I expect to the performance or memory usage?

Is it fine/permissible/recommended to enable NMT in Production at all times at "detail" level:

```
-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=detail
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Oracle Native Memory Tracking for Java 8 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr007.html):

> Get detail data: To get a more detailed view of native memory usage, start the JVM with command line option: -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=detail. This will track exactly what methods allocate the most memory. Enabling NMT will result in 5-10 percent JVM performance drop and memory usage for NMT adds 2 words to all malloc memory as malloc header. NMT memory usage is also tracked by NMT.

Once NMT is enabled the jcmd output for VM.native_memory will actually record what looks like the memory allocation overhead due to having NMT enabled:

```
#jcmd 25 VM.native_memory
25:

Native Memory Tracking:

Total: reserved=2724013KB, committed=1526785KB
-                 Java Heap (reserved=1048576KB, committed=1048576KB)
                        (mmap: reserved=1048576KB, committed=1048576KB)
...

    Native Memory Tracking (reserved=6004KB, committed=6004KB)
                        (malloc=384KB #6040)
                        (tracking overhead=5621KB)
```