# Docker kills java container due to OOM but no signs of high memory usage in JMX statistics

Tags: java, docker, out-of-memory, heap-memory

We have a Docker container with a Java 11 application running on AWS ECS. The service is configured to be killed once it uses 1,5GB of RAM

```
"memory": 1500,
"memoryReservation": 1137,
```

[image: AWS ECS metrics of said service]

The problem is that we don't see this increased memory usage reflected in our dashboards
[image]
[image]
[image]
(p.s. the flatline in the grafana dashboards is due to Prometheus no longer receiving metrics).

We have done pretty much everything possible to limit the amount of on- and offheap memory Java is allowed to use and if I check the output of NMT it's reserved usage is at most 1,1GB. Our command line right now is this:

```
java ‑Xmx600m ‑XX:+UseG1GC ‑XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=220m 
‑XX:+PrintFlagsFinal ‑XX:NewRatio=1 ‑XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=40m 
‑Xss512k ‑XX:ProfiledCodeHeapSize=70M ‑XX:NonProfiledCodeHeapSize=50M 
‑XX:NonNMethodCodeHeapSize=8M ‑XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing 
‑XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=32M ‑XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128M 
‑XX:+SegmentedCodeCache ‑javaagent:/opentelemetry‑javaagent.jar 
‑Dotel.javaagent.extensions=/opentelemetry‑java‑ecs‑extension‑all.jar 
‑Dotel.resource.attributes=xxx,aws.ecs.launchtype=ec2 
‑XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary ‑XX:‑OmitStackTraceInFastThrow 
‑Dspring.profiles.active=prd‑ecs ‑Dspring.cloud.consul.host=172.17.42.1 
‑Dspring.cloud.consul.config.watch.enabled=false 
‑Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999 
‑Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
‑Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
‑Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true ‑Dserver.port=8080 
‑Daws.paramstore.enabled=true 
‑Daws.paramstore.region=eu‑west‑1 
‑Dspring.main.banner‑mode=off ‑jar /1234‑service.jar
```

We are kind of clueless on how it's possible that all of a sudden our containers use 400MB memory without any sign of it in the JMX metrics.

//edit: the output of the NMT of the oldest running container

```
Native Memory Tracking:

Total: reserved=1180115KB, committed=700171KB
-                 Java Heap (reserved=614400KB, committed=260096KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=614400KB, committed=260096KB)

-                     Class (reserved=215344KB, committed=208080KB)
                            (classes #35567)
                            (  instance classes #33401, array classes #2166)
                            (malloc=8496KB #125896)
                            (mmap: reserved=206848KB, committed=199584KB)
                            (  Metadata:   )
                            (    reserved=174080KB, committed=173536KB)
                            (    used=167363KB)
                            (    free=6173KB)
                            (    waste=0KB =0.00%)
                            (  Class space:)
                            (    reserved=32768KB, committed=26048KB)
                            (    used=22342KB)
                            (    free=3706KB)
                            (    waste=0KB =0.00%)

-                    Thread (reserved=77858KB, committed=16034KB)
                            (thread #125)
                            (stack: reserved=77260KB, committed=15436KB)
                            (malloc=452KB #752)
                            (arena=146KB #249)

-                      Code (reserved=139426KB, committed=96022KB)
                            (malloc=7330KB #29103)
                            (mmap: reserved=132096KB, committed=88692KB)

-                        GC (reserved=70010KB, committed=56862KB)
                            (malloc=14362KB #61984)
                            (mmap: reserved=55648KB, committed=42500KB)

-                  Compiler (reserved=896KB, committed=896KB)
                            (malloc=764KB #2798)
                            (arena=133KB #5)

-                  Internal (reserved=4509KB, committed=4509KB)
                            (malloc=4477KB #3670)
                            (mmap: reserved=32KB, committed=32KB)

-                     Other (reserved=4359KB, committed=4359KB)
                            (malloc=4359KB #39)

-                    Symbol (reserved=37775KB, committed=37775KB)
                            (malloc=34219KB #439593)
                            (arena=3556KB #1)

-    Native Memory Tracking (reserved=10765KB, committed=10765KB)
                            (malloc=34KB #437)
                            (tracking overhead=10731KB)

-               Arena Chunk (reserved=190KB, committed=190KB)
                            (malloc=190KB)

-                   Logging (reserved=4KB, committed=4KB)
                            (malloc=4KB #194)

-                 Arguments (reserved=20KB, committed=20KB)
                            (malloc=20KB #545)

-                    Module (reserved=3692KB, committed=3692KB)
                            (malloc=3692KB #14082)

-              Synchronizer (reserved=860KB, committed=860KB)
                            (malloc=860KB #7286)

-                 Safepoint (reserved=8KB, committed=8KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=8KB, committed=8KB)
```

//edit2: our Docker image we use on our 90+ Docker service

```
FROM --platform=$TARGETPLATFORM amazoncorretto:11

RUN yum install -y shadow-utils wget && yum clean all
RUN wget https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/releases/latest/download/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar -O /opentelemetry-javaagent.jar
ADD opentelemetry-java-ecs-extension-*-all.jar /opentelemetry-java-ecs-extension-all.jar
RUN adduser docker
RUN if [ -f $JAVA_HOME/conf/security/java.security ]; then sed -i 's/^networkaddress.cache.ttl/#networkaddress.cache.ttl/g' $JAVA_HOME/conf/security/java.security; fi && \
    echo "networkaddress.cache.ttl=30" >> $JAVA_HOME/conf/security/java.security

USER docker
```

//edit3: forgot to mention that we've also set this env var

```
            {
                "name": "MALLOC_ARENA_MAX",
                "value": "4"
            }
```

Comment: You didn't provide the image you were using. The OS also uses some memory. Have you tried an Alpine based jre image?

Comment: We use amazoncorretto:11 as base image. I know there is some overhead of the container's OS, but why the sudden peak of 400MB ?

Comment: Your CPU usage also went through the roof. It might be the case that the usage jumped faster than it could write the usage before the container got yeeted.

Comment: It seems worse than it is. We only reserve .195 vCPU for our containers, so 100% is actually just 20% CPU but it's a thought that did cross my mind. We already push metrics every 4s, we can try to push them even more frequently to see if that helps.

Comment: Does the container get killed gracefully or forcefully? The application might send the last metrics when it gets shut down when it was shut down properly.

Comment: We get an exit code -137, so that's a straigtht OOM kill by docker which is equivalent to doing kill -9 on the java process. So the last 4s might be missing but if you look at the Cloudwatch metrics it peaks for longer than 4 seconds before being killed (though those metrics are very sparse).

Comment: Small update. We've just migrated our test environment to the latest Amazon Linux 2 AMI and made sure that everything was as default as it could be. We drained the old servers and ECS moved everything to the new servers and hell broke loose. Suddenly, a ton of services needed more memory than they needed before and were killed by the OOM killer.
At this point, we're pretty clueless about what's going on.

Comment: Have you tried running the application without providing the memory and memoryReservation configuration options? I think it could be of help to estimate the actual amount of memory required by your container and by the different processes that run on it.

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451103/java-using-much-more-memory-than-heap-size-or-size-correctly-docker-memory-limi/53624438#53624438)?

Answer (score 1):

Java is not very good at managing ram resources as limit. Java started in a world of PCs where you had RAM and SWAP memory so whenever you tweak the values is for keeping it running as best as it can.

When docker came into existence, java applications started having a new issue to face, there is no more SWAP to use, and now the memory java is able to see as available (host) is not equal as the memory the docker was allocated as a limit.

For example, your java app might be reporting to use 1.1Gb of RAM but, while you allocate 1.5Gb RAM to your task definition, this is not what JAVA is able to see natively. If you are able to ssh into the container, you would be able to see that the RAM it reports is the host container instance where the task is running. Let's say you have a t4g.small with 2 cpus and 2 Gb RAM running your task. That means Java is going to see those limits and some components might calculate over that limit. From there you need to consider any other processes memory like OS, network, root processes, internal logging, etc.

Your Cloudwatch dashboard actually shows the real usage of all those components as a whole, while your JAVA dashboards only reports selected components that it monitors. So you are blind to know what else is consuming memory.

NOTE: Also remember that Native Memory Tracking is not able to see all java related memory usage. It does help to understand how memory is mostly being used so you can improve the settings but is a close guess, not the real consumption.

Suggestion: While working with java apps in containerized environments is best to leave more room for you to start tracking historical data. Like give it 8Gb for a month, understand who your app behaves and optimize accordingly. Then, let your historical data give you a hint on where the limit should be. Do not place a small limit first and try to make your java app behave later.

Answer (score 0):

We also had at a point in time trouble with OOM and java within containers.
We also tried to set a lot of parameters, at some point stumbled upon the Alibaba guidelines, which recommended ([best-practices-for-jvm-heap-size-configuration](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/en/sae/use-cases/best-practices-for-jvm-heap-size-configuration)):

```
-XX:InitialRAMPercentage=70.0 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=70.0
```

We were successful in limiting the JVM to 70 percent of the available memory. Some containers are also behaving quite good with 80 percent, but these do have a lot less pressure on the garbage collector. So we set now our containers with a default of 70 percent, this also sets the initial RAM and maximum RAM to 70 percent.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried launching with `-Xmx1492M` as one of the arguments passed to java?  I also like [S.Spieker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1287864/s-spieker)'s [Suggestion of using initial and max ram percentages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78213829/8906994) with `-XX:InitialRAMPercentage=70.0 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=70.0` there is a strikingly similar question posed a while back with [a much more in-depth explanation of java in docker containers that can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38597965/difference-between-resident-set-size-rss-and-java-total-committed-memory-nmt).