# Java memory usage way higher than reported by Native Memory Tracking

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jvm

when trying to optimize the memory footprint of a Java (Spring Boot) application I noticed that memory usage is higher than I expected.

For investigation I used Java's [Native Memory Tracking (NMT)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/troubleshoot/diagnostic-tools.html#GUID-1F53A50E-86FF-491D-A023-8EC4F1D1AC77) feature, which reports 601040KB (~600MB) being committed.

```
> jcmd 1 VM.native_memory
1:

Native Memory Tracking:

(Omitting categories weighting less than 1KB)

Total: reserved=18460740KB, committed=601040KB
       malloc: 97616KB #503895
       mmap:   reserved=18363124KB, committed=503424KB

-                 Java Heap (reserved=16465920KB, committed=262144KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=16465920KB, committed=262144KB)
[...]
```

However, system tools like top or ps report way more memory being used (~1GB resident set size / ~1.3GB memory size):

```
> ps -e -o pid,pmem,rss,size,cmd
    PID %MEM   RSS  SIZE CMD
      1  1.6 1061716 1311316 java org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
[...]
```

The only clue I found in the NMT documentation is

> Since NMT doesn't track memory allocations by non-JVM code, you may have to use tools supported by the operating system to detect memory leaks in native code.

But I'm not sure what non-JVM could be allocating hundreds of megabytes of memory. Is there a way to find out what is using all that memory?

Thank you in advance!

---

Additional information:

```
> jcmd 1 VM.flags
1:
-XX:CICompilerCount=12 -XX:ConcGCThreads=3 -XX:G1ConcRefinementThreads=13 -XX:G1EagerReclaimRemSetThreshold=64 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=8388608 -XX:G1PeriodicGCInterval=60000 -XX:G1RemSetArrayOfCardsEntries=64 -XX:G1RemSetHowlMaxNumBuckets=8 -XX:G1RemSetHowlNumBuckets=8 -XX:GCDrainStackTargetSize=64 -XX:InitialHeapSize=1056964608 -XX:MarkStackSize=4194304 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxHeapSize=16861102080 -XX:MaxNewSize=10116661248 -XX:MinHeapDeltaBytes=8388608 -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=5 -XX:MinHeapSize=268435456 -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=detail -XX:NonNMethodCodeHeapSize=7602480 -XX:NonProfiledCodeHeapSize=122027880 -XX:+PrintGC -XX:ProfiledCodeHeapSize=122027880 -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=251658240 -XX:+SegmentedCodeCache -XX:SoftMaxHeapSize=268435456 -XX:-THPStackMitigation -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseG1GC
```

```
> jcmd 1 VM.system_properties
1:
#Thu Feb 08 11:52:42 CET 2024
CONSOLE_LOG_CHARSET=UTF-8
FILE_LOG_CHARSET=UTF-8
PID=1
catalina.base=/tmp/tomcat.8080.1256868023389071013
catalina.home=/tmp/tomcat.8080.1256868023389071013
catalina.useNaming=false
file.encoding=UTF-8
file.separator=/
java.awt.headless=true
java.class.path=.
java.class.version=65.0
java.home=/opt/java/openjdk
java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib\:/usr/lib64\:/lib64\:/lib\:/usr/lib
java.runtime.name=OpenJDK Runtime Environment
java.runtime.version=21.0.1+12-LTS
java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.specification.version=21
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
java.vendor.url=https\://adoptium.net/
java.vendor.url.bug=https\://github.com/adoptium/adoptium-support/issues
java.vendor.version=Temurin-21.0.1+12
java.version=21.0.1
java.version.date=2023-10-17
java.vm.compressedOopsMode=Zero based
java.vm.info=mixed mode, sharing
java.vm.name=OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vm.specification.version=21
java.vm.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
java.vm.version=21.0.1+12-LTS
jdk.debug=release
line.separator=\n
native.encoding=UTF-8
os.arch=amd64
os.name=Linux
os.version=5.18.13-200.fc36.x86_64
path.separator=\:
spring.beaninfo.ignore=true
stderr.encoding=UTF-8
stdout.encoding=UTF-8
sun.arch.data.model=64
sun.boot.library.path=/opt/java/openjdk/lib
sun.cpu.endian=little
sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle
sun.java.command=org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD
sun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8
sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
user.country=US
user.dir=/application
user.home=/root
user.language=en
user.name=root
user.timezone=Europe/Berlin
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does GC release back memory to OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458195/does-gc-release-back-memory-to-os)

Comment: Hey @teapot418 the garbage collection is working just as I expect (NMT is showing the committed memory for the heap to be exactly equal to SoftMaxHeapSize). I'm just wondering what is using all that memory which is not reported by NMT :)

Comment: My point is that the jvm will wait until some proportion (I seem to remember 75% as a rule of thumb) of its memory is unused before giving it back to the operating system. You can try some of the tunables in the linked Q if they make any difference.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! You are right, the default value for MaxHeapFreeRatio ist 70%, I already decreased that to 20%, the comitted memory is successfully shrinked just as I expect. I'm under the impression that committed memory == the memory acutally used from the operating system. Maybe I'm mistaken here?

Comment: I can't find good detailed information on `committed`, but at least [there is support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38597965/difference-between-resident-set-size-rss-and-java-total-committed-memory-nmt) for the claim that committed!=RSS. One of the answers there also raises the possibility of malloc peculiarities (see `export MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=2`).

Comment: Aah yes, thank you for the tip about `MALLOC_ARENA_MAX`!

Setting that to 2 did reduce the RSS to ~700MB, which is still more than I expected, but a lot better. 

In the comments of the linked question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041117 I found a github issue about native memory linking, and the command `jcmd System.trim_native_heap` - when I ran that command it freed an additional 100MB of memory: 

`Trim native heap: RSS+Swap: 681M->576M (-104M)`

which resulted in the RSS being more or less equal to the committed memory reported by NMT.

Thank you, I will look into that!