# Apache2 starting with high amount of memory allocated

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, ubuntu, memory

I've an Ubuntu Linux 16.04.1 server, running a wordpress blog my server hardware is pretty ok for this task but I found that apache2 is loading too much memory.

After i JUST REBOOT the server the OS shows me this consume

```
2215    www-data    563.27 MB   /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
2216    www-data    563.27 MB   /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
2217    www-data    563.27 MB   /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

It's a pretty high value for a server before any request, I found the config file setting the number of spare servers to 3 after start up and it is okay.

but the amount of memory each server loads is what making me confuse and i didnt found any configuration to set this value or a min or max.

Does anyone know the default value for an apache php mysql running a wordpress?

are there any config file i can check for understand why such high memory?

Comment: you are using mod_php, right?

Comment: Is this number in your output Virtual Memory Size (VSZ) or Resident Set Size (RSS)?

Comment: ezra-s yes
@ErkiA virtual

Comment: Then it doesn't actually show, how much memory server "consumes": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880784/what-is-rss-and-vsz-in-linux-memory-management