# Sum of RSS memory in ps less than memory actually used

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, redhat, ps

We have two machines with identical configuration and use (we have two balanced Siebel application servers in them).

Normally, we have a very similar RAM usage in them (around 7 Gb).
Recently, we've have a sudden increase of RAM in only one of them and now we have close to 14 Gb utilization of RAM in that machine.

So, for very similar boxes, we have one of them using 7Gb of RAM while the other one is consuming 14 Gb.

Now, using *ps aux* command to determine which process it's using all this additional memory, we see memory consumption is very similar in both machines. Somehow, we don't see any process that's using those 7 Gb of additional RAM.

Let's see:

`Machine 1:
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         15943      15739        204          0        221       1267
-/+ buffers/cache:      14249       1693
Swap:         8191          0       8191`

So, we have 14249 Mb usage of RAM.

`Machine 2:
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         15943      15636        306          0        962       6409
-/+ buffers/cache:       8264       7678
Swap:         8191          0       8191`

So, we have 8264 Mb usage of RAM.

I guess, the sum of Resident Set Size memory of ps should be equal or bigger to this value. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880784/what-is-rss-and-vsz-in-linux-memory-management) is how much memory is allocated to the process and is in RAM (including memory from shared libraries). We don't have any memory in SWAP.

However:

Machine 1:

`ps aux | awk 'BEGIN {sum=0} {sum +=$6} END {print sum/1024}'
8357.08`

8357.08 < 14249 -> NOK!

Machine 2:

`ps aux | awk 'BEGIN {sum=0} {sum +=$6} END {print sum/1024}'
8468.63`

8468.63 > 8264 -> OK

What do I get wrong? How can I find where this "missing" memory is?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The ps figure won't take account of shared memory between process and so comparing summed data from ps with free is difficult.

Comment: That's right, Raman but, as a consquence, I would exepect ps ouptut to be bigger that the one from free not the other way around.

Comment: Free includes shared memory between processes and ps doesn't. Free therefore is normally bigger.

Comment: Thank you for your insight Raman, however I understand: "Resident Set Size is the amount of physical memory currently allocated and used by a process (without swapped out pages). It includes the code, data and shared libraries (which are counted in every process which uses them)". See http://trustmeiamadeveloper.com/2016/03/18/where-is-my-memory-java from Mikhail Krestjaninoff.

Comment: @user3779018 Just met the same problem, do you have any progress?

Comment: I have same issue, did you find a solution/way to troubleshoot further?

Answer (score 0):

If them two are virtual machines, maybe the "missing" memory is occupied by Balloon driver, especially they are hosted by VMware ESXi.

Recently I encounter the similar scenario. Sum of all process RSS is 14GB, command `free` shows 26GB used, so there are 12GB memory missing.

After search on internet, I follow [this article](https://www.digihunch.com/2020/05/understanding-where-the-memory-goes-on-linux-vm/) and execute command `vmware-toolbox-cmd stat balloon` on my VM, console shows 12xxxMB (used by balloon), BINGO!