# How to measure number of allocated page tables?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, page-fault

As far as I know, Linux does not allocate page tables until needed (allocation happens on-demand as pages are used). 
I want to check how many page tables are really allocated during program execution.
Could you please let me know how can I measure the number of actually allocated pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to measure number of page tables of running program.

You can use `RSS` value to calculate number of active page tables:

> RSS is the Resident Set Size and is used to show how much memory is
>   allocated to that process and is in RAM. It does not include memory
>   that is swapped out. It does include memory from shared libraries as
>   long as the pages from those libraries are actually in memory. It does
>   include all stack and heap memory.

Use the `RSS` and divide into page table size (by default it is 4KB).

For instance, I want to count page tables of tmux on my machine:

```
$ ps aux | grep tmux
da       21995  0.0  0.0  26416  2768 ?        Ss   May17   4:16 tmux
```

The RSS value is 2768 and if we divide it by 4: **692**.

But note that RSS also counts shared libraries. If I do `cat /proc/21995/maps`, there will be complete list of memory mappings of tmux, most of them are glibc shared libraries.

References:

- [What is RSS and VSZ in Linux memory management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880784/what-is-rss-and-vsz-in-linux-memory-management)
- https://manybutfinite.com/post/how-the-kernel-manages-your-memory/