# Limiting the memory usage of a program in Linux

Tags: linux, memory, limit, ulimit, setrlimit

I'm new to Linux and Terminal (or whatever kind of command prompt it uses), and I want to control the amount of RAM a process can use. I already looked for hours to find an easy-t-use guide. I have a few requirements for limiting it:

1. Multiple instances of the program will be running, but I only want to limit some of the instances.
2. I do not want the process to crash once it exceeds the limit. I want it to use HDD page swap.
3. The program will run under WINE, and is a .exe.

So can somebody please help with the command to limit the RAM usage on a process in Linux?

Comment: See this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44985/limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process

Comment: I have already looked at that source many times, and it is not useful since it does not give the full code after "$pdftoppm".

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you’re using Wine makes no difference in this particular context, which leaves requirements 1 and 2.  Requirement 2 –

> I do not want the process to crash once it exceeds the limit. I want it to use HDD page swap.

– is known as limiting the *resident set size* or *rss* of the process, and it’s actually rather nontrivial to do on Linux, as is demonstrated by [a question asked in 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043709/resident-set-size-rss-limit-has-no-effect).  You’ll need to set up [Linux control groups (cgroups)](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/cgroups.txt).  Fortunately, [Justin L.’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043709/resident-set-size-rss-limit-has-no-effect#6365534) gives a brief rundown on how to do so.  Note that

- instead of `jlebar`, you should use your own Unix user name, and
- instead of `your/program`, you should use `wine /path/to/Windows/program.exe`.

Using cgroups will also satisfy your other requirements – you can start as many instances of the program as you wish, but only those which you start with `cgexec -g memory:limited` will be limited.