# How do I use `setrlimit` to limit memory usage? RLIMIT_AS kills too soon; RLIMIT_DATA, RLIMIT_RSS, RLIMIT_STACK kill not at all

Tags: python, numpy, memory, setrlimit

I'm trying to use `setrlimit` to limit my memory usage on a Linux system, in order to stop my process from crashing the machine (my code was crashing nodes on a high performance cluster, because a bug led to memory consumption in excess of 100 GiB).  I can't seem to find the correct resource to pass to `setrlimit`; I think it should be resident, which [cannot be limited with setrlimit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043709/resident-set-size-rss-limit-has-no-effect), but I am confused by resident, heap, stack.  In the code below; if I uncomment only `RLIMIT_AS`, the code fails with `MemoryError` at `numpy.ones(shape=(1000, 1000, 10), dtype="f8")` even though that array should be only 80 MB.  If I uncomment only `RLIMIT_DATA`, `RLIMIT_RSS`, or `RLIMIT_STACK` both arrays get allocated successfully, even though the total memory usage is 2 GB, or twice the desired maximum.

I would like to make make my program fail (no matter how) as soon as it tries to allocate too much RAM.  Why do none of `RLIMIT_DATA`, `RLIMIT_RSS`, `RLIMIT_STACK` and `RLIMIT_AS` do what I mean, and what is the correct resource to pass to `setrlimit`?

```
$ cat mwe.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5

import resource
import numpy

#rsrc = resource.RLIMIT_AS
#rsrc = resource.RLIMIT_DATA
#rsrc = resource.RLIMIT_RSS
#rsrc = resource.RLIMIT_STACK

soft, hard = resource.getrlimit(rsrc)
print("Limit starts as:", soft, hard)

resource.setrlimit(rsrc, (1e9, 1e9))

soft, hard = resource.getrlimit(rsrc)
print("Limit is now:", soft, hard)
print("Allocating 80 KB, should certainly work")
M1 = numpy.arange(100*100, dtype="u8")

print("Allocating 80 MB, should work")
M2 = numpy.arange(1000*1000*10, dtype="u8")

print("Allocating 2 GB, should fail")
M3 = numpy.arange(1000*1000*250, dtype="u8")

input("Still here…")
```

Output with the `RLIMIT_AS` line uncommented:

```
$ ./mwe.py 
Limit starts as: -1 -1
Limit is now: 1000000000 -1
Allocating 80 KB, should certainly work
Allocating 80 MB, should work
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mwe.py", line 22, in <module>
    M2 = numpy.arange(1000*1000*10, dtype="u8")
MemoryError
```

Output when running with any of the other ones uncommented:

```
$ ./mwe.py 
Limit starts as: -1 -1
Limit is now: 1000000000 -1
Allocating 80 KB, should certainly work
Allocating 80 MB, should work
Allocating 2 GB, should fail
Still here…
```

At the final line, `top` reports that my process is using 379 GB VIRT, 2.0 GB RES.

---

System details:

```
$ uname -a
Linux host.somewhere.ac.uk 2.6.32-573.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Aug 10 09:44:54 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago)

$ free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2.0T       1.9T        37G       1.6G       3.4G       1.8T
-/+ buffers/cache:        88G       1.9T 
Swap:         464G       4.8M       464G 

$ python3.5 --version
Python 3.5.0

$ python3.5 -c "import numpy; print(numpy.__version__)"
1.11.1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting stacksize in a python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061582/setting-stacksize-in-a-python-script)

Comment: Attempting to set `rlimit_stack` after [Stack Clash](http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2017/06/19/1) remediations may result in failure or related problems. Also see Red Hat [Issue 1463241](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1463241)

Comment: I also run your script, it works fine.
The problem must be in your personal config.

Answer (score 3):

Alas I have no answer for your question. But I hope the following might help:

- Your script works as expected on my system. Please share exact spec for yours, might be there is a known problem with Linux distro, kernel or even numpy...
- You should be OK with `RLIMIT_AS`. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33525161/404099) this should limit the entire virtual memory used by the process. And virtual memory includes all: swap memory, shared libraries, code and data. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21049737/404099).
- You may add the following function (adopted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/938800/404099)) to your script to check actual virtual memory usage at any point:

  ```
  def peak_virtual_memory_mb():
      with open('/proc/self/status') as f:
          status = f.readlines()
          vmpeak = next(s for s in status if s.startswith("VmPeak:"))
          return vmpeak
  ```
- A general advice, disable swap memory. In my experience with high performance servers it does more harm than solves problems.

Comment: I have added some system details.  Do I need to add more?  `top` reports that I'm using 379 GB virtual memory.  I don't know why, but it probably explains why the `RLIMIT_AS` version fails early.  NB: I am just a user on this server and not in a position to disable swap memory.

Comment: Yes, indeed 379GB is really strange, and it might explain the early failure. What Linux flavor the machine runs? Have you tried to `print peak_virtual_memory_mb()` before and after memory allocation? BTW, probably best not to share the hostname on public site :)

Comment: @It's Redhat Enterprise Linux (see edit).  I'm not sure how to print the peak virtual memory.

Comment: Well. Haven't found anything on Redhat. See my answer above for the code to print VM. Or you may run memory profiler on your script - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler. I fear I have no more ideas :)