# Limit RAM: python crashes instead of MemoryError

Tags: python, memory

I have a python programme which sometimes consumes a lot of RAM.
I tried to restrict the usage by
`resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS, (2**32, 2**32))`
However, this causes Python to crash instead of raising a `MemoryError`.

How do I keep Python alive? I.e. I *want* the MemoryError.

The problem appears, when I try to solve a large instance in cvxpy. (This also means I cannot reduce memory usage of the code - it is not *my* code.)
But when I allocate large amounts of RAM via

- numpy (`numpy.arange(1000*1000*250, dtype="u8")`,
  from [How do I use `setrlimit` to limit memory usage? RLIMIT_AS kills too soon; RLIMIT_DATA, RLIMIT_RSS, RLIMIT_STACK kill not at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39755928/how-do-i-use-setrlimit-to-limit-memory-usage-rlimit-as-kills-too-soon-rlimit)), or
- shell (call `yes | tr \\n x | head -c $((1024*1024*1024*10)) | grep n`,
  from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99334/how-to-fill-90-of-the-free-memory)

then i get the `MemoryError` as expected.

What is the difference?

Edit: The error message is:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
>    what():  std::bad_alloc

Edit: I now have a (M)WE.

```
import cvxpy as cvx
import numpy as np
import random
import resource
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS, (2**32, 2**32))

# Problem data.
m = 500
n = 500
np.random.seed(1)
random.seed(1)
A = np.random.randn(m, n)
b = np.random.randn(m, 1)

# Construct the problem.
X = cvx.Semidef(m)
objective = cvx.Minimize(cvx.sum_entries(cvx.norm(X)))
constraints = [sum([X[random.randint(0,499),random.randint(0,499)] for _ in range(50)]) >= random.random() for _ in range(5000)]
prob = cvx.Problem(objective, constraints)

print("Optimal value", prob.solve(solver = 'SCS'))
```

After a few seconds it starts taking up large amounts of memory (more than 1GB, which is supposed to be the limit) and then crashes with the above error.

Comment: What exactly means "causes Python to crash"? Is there a stacktrace?

Answer (score 3):

Python only throws a MemoryError if it can figure out the error is going to happen before it actually happens. Otherwise, it will crash. Check out the official description of the MemoryError:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.MemoryError