# Using getline vs fgets for basic file printing

Tags: c, posix, fgets, getline

I am using the following to print the lines of a file:

```
int main() {

    FILE *fptr = fopen("test20k.csv", "r");
    char buffer[MAXLINE];

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fptr) != NULL)
        printf("%s", buffer);
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;

}
```

How would the same thing be done using `getline`? Here is a similar question which is more conceptual: [getline() vs. fgets(): Control memory allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55970169/getline-vs-fgets-control-memory-allocation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply check [getline(3) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) to determine the appropriate parameter types to pass and the return type to handle and how `getline` indicates success/failure.

Then all that is needed is to replace `fgets()` with `getline()` in your code. All *line-oriented* input functions read and include the trailing `'\n'`, so no change there. However, note that `getline()` allocates storage for your `buffer`, so you will need to `free()` the `buffer` when you are done with it -- requiring that your include `stdlib.h` in addition to `stdio.h`.

Further, you note that `getline` is not part of the standard C library. Instead `getline` is a POSIX function, so not every implementation of C need provide it, so you may have portability issues.

That's basically it. Though, in your code you should not use *hardcoded filenames*. That is one reason why `main()` accepts parameters. So simply pass the filename to read as the first argument to your program (you can also read from `stdin` by default if no argument is provided)

Putting it all together, as a minimum implementation, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    size_t n = 0;           /* initial alloc size, 0 - getline decides */
    char *buffer = NULL;    /* pointer to block of mem holding input */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fptr = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fptr) {    /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    /* you pass the address of your buffer and a pointer to n */
    while (getline (&buffer, &n, fptr) != -1)
        printf("%s", buffer);
    putchar('\n');

    if (fptr != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fptr);

    free (buffer);      /* getline allocates, don't forget to free */

    return 0;
}
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/getline_file dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

Answer (score 0):

`fgets()/getline()` are commonly used to read *text*.

Uncommonly, the input stream contain a *null character* `'\0'`.

`fgets()` reads a *null character* like any character.  It does not stop reading the *line* of input.

The below only prints to the first *null character*  encountered in the *string* - it lacks a distinction from a read *null character* and the appended *null character* that `fgets()` adds.

```
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fptr)) {
  printf("%s", buffer);  // Maybe stops too early?
}
```

---

[`getline()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), though non-standard C, has an advantage as it returns the numbers of characters read.  Printing can then print to the count returned, rather than only to the first *null character*.

```
size_t n = 0;
char *buffer = NULL;

ssize_t sz;
while ((sz = getline (&buffer, &n, fptr)) != -1) {
  fwrite(buffer, 1, sz, stdout);
}

free(buffer);
```

---

Notes: `size_t n = 0; char *buffer = NULL;` are the initial settings. `getline (&buffer, &n, ...)` receives the address of those 2 variables allowing it to update those two (due to re-allocation) as needed.  Max buffer size is `SIZE_MAX` or the limits of the memory pool. We do not need to know how it works exactly within `getline()` as that is an implementation detail that varies.

---

Although *null characters* are uncommon is simple text files, I have found writing code that is best to  [be prepared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scout_Motto) for for *null characters*.  They readily come up is reading a text file that is [UTF16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) encoded. Of course expecting an ASCII or [UTF8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) texting file and getting a UTF16 one is a problem, nicely printing thought *null characters* helps ID the issue.

Comment: thanks for this answer. One question -- why do you set the `*buffer` to NULL? And why is &n = 0 as well. If everything is set to zero, what is the maximum buffer size you can use, or how does that work exactly?